# PHP is_numeric error handling if value not set

Tags: php

I have the following code in PHP

```
if (is_numeric($args['myargs']['custom_value'])) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

It runs correctly, but if custom_value is not set then I get the warning in my logs..

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: custom_value
```

I think this is just a notice and not an error so can be safely ignored? Is it bad practice to do it like this?

Comment: You just need to check if it exist like `if(isset($args['myargs']['custom_value'])){}`

Comment: that means the array: `$args['myargs']` doesn't have an index of `custom_value`

Comment: Every time you write code and a notice gets triggered it happens because someone from the PHP Team took the time to implement it. Notices are a language feature designed to spot potential bugs. Can you "safely" ignore it? You can surely ignore it but that means opting out intentionally from the tool because as soon your app floods the logs with notices the overall feature becomes useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to avoid the warning you should do something like this

```
if(isset($args['myargs']['custom_value'])) {
  if (is_numeric($args['myargs']['custom_value'])) {
      echo 'Yes';
  } else {
      echo 'No';
  }
}
```

Comment: You can just test `isset($args['myargs']['custom_value'])` and skip the other two tests. PHP won't throw an error if you use `isset` and the higher level elements are not defined.

Answer (score 2):

**What's happening**

PHP sees you are trying to use an array element that is not set, so it helpfully warns you about it. It's not serious in this case, but you want to learn to avoid the messages.

**The solution**

The function `isset` will test if the array key is defined.

```
//You must first of all test isset and then is_numeric,
// else you still get the error. Research 'short circuiting' in php 
if ( isset($args['myargs']['custom_value']) && is_numeric($args['myargs']['custom_value'])) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

This solution will also print "No" if the array key was never defined.

Answer (score 1):

alse you can

```
error_reporting(0)
```

in php file beginning